# Calling an API defaults to http: which is causing it to be blocked by Safari

Tags: javascript, api, safari

I am using an API to generate pins on a Google Map but it is being blocked on Safari for serving insecure content. I am calling the https: version of the API but it is saying that the content is coming from the http: version.

```
function callSpotAPI(lat, lng){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"https://www2.itemlocator.net/ils/locatorJSON",
        data: {
            //API data
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            //Handle Success
        },
        error: function() {
            //Handle Error
        }
    })
}
```

This script is returning this warning on Safari:
[blocked] The page at https://www.my-site.com/pages/product-locator was not allowed to run insecure content from http://www2.itemlocator.net/ils/locatorJSON/?callback=jQuery33105072229741619069_1559653172805&customer=_____&item=_____&lat=_____&long=_____&radius=20&_=1559653172806.

I omitted the actual data that is being sent just incase that is sensitive, better safe than sorry, but this app is working fine on Chrome and Firefox which is what is really confusing me. Why is it trying to run content from the http: when I clearly have https: in the ajax call?

Comment: `dataType: "jsonp",` and `type: "POST",` are incompatible. JSONP requests are **always** GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are requesting is responding with an HTTP redirect to a non-HTTPS URL.

> ```
> [ ~ ] ➜  curl -I "https://www2.itemlocator.net/ils/locatorJSON"
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2019 14:02:15 GMT
> Server: CherryPy/3.2.2
> Content-Length: 143
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
> Location: http://www2.itemlocator.net/ils/locatorJSON/
> Connection: close
> ```

The correct URL appears to be `https://www2.itemlocator.net/ils/locatorJSON/` (with a `/` on the end).

Comment: So that one / is what caused the problem... I really hate coding sometimes lol. Thanks for the help man I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

I am not very much sure about this but sometimes safari gives this error because of certificate issues. You can try adding 'https://www2.itemlocator.net' into safari certificates.

Comment: Is this something I would need to do on my Safari that would only affect it on my computer? I need a solution that will work for everyone as this is a public site

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the certificate for that URL. If there was, the error message wouldn't complain about `http://etc` (without an `s`).

Answer (score -1):

So after a bit of Googling, the solution that worked for me was just to add this meta tag to the site:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

I'm not very well versed in meta tags but the app is now working so that's good. If anyone see anything wrong with doing it this way please let me know so I don't mess something up but for now this is my solution.